# Differentiation of the cosine and sine power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I know that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (x-a)^n$ is a power series with radius of convergence $R$ and $f\colon (a-R,a+R)\to\mathbb{R}$ is the function such that $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (x-a)^n$ then $f$ is differentiable on $(a-R,a+R)$ and for any $0<r<R$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_n (x-a)^{n-1}$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on the interval $[a-r,a+r]$.

Now, since $\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$ and $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$ we have $\cos'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n)\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2(n+1))\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}x^{2(n+1)-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2n+2}{2n+2}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}=-\sin(x)$
 and 
$\sin'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n+1)\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$ and now I'm stuck: I don't know how to recover from here the series of $\cos(x)$.

So, where I'm going wrong?

Comment: In the power series for $\sin'(x)$ the sum should be from $n=0,$ not from $n=1$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As far as I can see the theorem I cited at the beginning of my question says otherwise. Am I applying it in the wrong way?

Comment: See your line "Now, since....". The lowest-degree term in the $\sin$ series is $x$ so the lowest-degree term in the $\sin'$ series is $x'=1.$ In your last line the lowest-degree term in the series is $-x^2/2.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Ok thanks but this raises the question: is the theorem I've applied wrong or is it correct and I am applying it in the wrong way?

Comment: You are using the right method and the theorem is right but  in the last line you have a missing term in the series, basically a clerical error.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet ok, thanks but could you tell me how to recover that missing term? I've been staring at this problem for a while but I still don't see how to correct my mistake.

Comment: Change the subscripts "$n=1$" on the summations  in the last line to "$n=0$".

Answer (score 1):

When you changed the limits in $cos'(x)$ from $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$
This is valid as the first term in differentiation of $cos (x)$ becomes $=0$, consequently you also changed $$n\implies n+1$$ in the equation,

But you didn't change$$n\implies n+1$$ after doing$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$
In $sin'(x)$

What you did was,
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$ $$\sin'(x)=\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\color{red}{n}}}{(2\color{red}{n})!}x^{2\color{red}{n}}$$ 
Actually it should be,
 $$\sin'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{(2(n+1))!}x^{2(n+1)}$$

Comment: I didn't do the change $n\Rightarrow n+1$ because I used the theorem I mentioned at the beginning of my question which (as far as I can see) does not require such a change. I shifted from $n$ to $n+1$ after the second $=$ sign using one of the properties of summation. If I tried to do the same in the second case I would get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}x^{2(n+1)}$.

Comment: Have you copied the theorem neatly? Does it work for when you have manipulated the $n$?

Comment: For example $$sin(x)=\sum_{n=0} (-1)^n\frac{x^{\color{red}{2n+1}}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Yes, I've just checked. The theorem is stated in the book I'm reading as I've stated it here.

Comment: Here we have manipulated $n$ to our needs `in sin x series`

Comment: Actual series should be$$\sum_{n=0}\frac{(\sin^{n'}(x))|_{x=0}}{n!}x^n$$

Comment: Because,$$sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$$$sin'(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\cdots$$

Comment: Probably it is compulsory for coeffecient of $(x-a)$  term to be equal to $n$ for the theorem to work, and your first attempt was just got luckily correct

Comment: Hence the theorem will work for $$\sum_{n=0}\frac{(\sin^{n'}(x))|_{x=0}}{n!}x^n$$

Comment: Then how can I apply that theorem? It's the only one about differentiation of power series that the book mentions.

Comment: I would advise to use it only when power of $x-a$ is $n$ and not $an+b$